# Getting a ThinApp App to find documents outside of the package

Tags: virtualization, vmware-thinapp

I am using VMWare ThinApp to package an application. Traditionally, the application has been shipped with documents and data as part of the package (eg charts, images, etc).

In order to decrease the package size, I'd like to be able to:

- Package the application without any documents
- Store the documents on the local hard drive of the machine that will run the ThinApp packaged version of the application.
- Have the ThinApp packaged application open the documents, as it would if they were in the package.

I'm running into trouble, as the application cannot find the files (presumably because it is encapsulated in ThinApp, and so is not actually looking on the hard drive in the usual place for them).

**How can I get an application, that has been packaged in ThinApp, to find documents on the hard drive, outside of the ThinApp package?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow an application to access files outside of the ThinApp package (or to deny access to files), the isolation mode needs to be correctly set on the application, and on the individual folders.

This article and video ([Understanding Isolation Modes In VMWare](http://blogs.vmware.com/kb/2011/04/understanding-isolation-modes-in-vmware-thinapp.html#.URtvPWehdC1)) is really useful; and explains the three isolation modes in full.

In this case, to allow the application to access files outside of the package, the folder should be created inside the app package, and set to have Merged permissions.
The content can then be placed on the local hard drive.